# How to stop beeping on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, audio

I am using a laptop and I have the sound muted but when in settings and I press backspace while search something it beeps loudly and I can’t find a way to turn it off.

Comment: Does the beeping stop after you stop pressing backspace?

Comment: You can either disable the `Terminal bell` in your terminal settings or remove the `pcspkr` driver using `modprobe -r pcspkr`

Comment: how do i get to the terminal settings

Answer (score 4):

I was looking to find a solution to this problem to turn off the beep in cherrytree note editor.

Editing inputrc did not work, but thanks to this post: https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/12/28/debian-how-to-turn-off-the-system-bell/ I managed to turn off the PC speaker beep:

1. create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/pcspkr-blacklist.conf`
2. add the following line: `blacklist pcspkr`
3. `sudo depmod -a`
4. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
5. reboot

Answer (score 0):

The beeping comes by default from Kali Linux and it has many reasons why it beeps. One way to turn it off is by opening a terminal and write:
`gedit /etc/inputrc`, then find a line which tells

`# set bell-style none`

Uncomment that line and it should work.